# make list of all the relevant data from excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

[image]

HI guys!

I'm trying to add some relevant information from my excel file using python.

The picture above is an example of the excel file I have to deal with.

Column A ; company number
Column B ; customer name (customer of the company stated on column A on the same row)
Column D ; report date

I want to add all the customer names with the same company number and the same report date.

For example, after processing data, It would be best to get the below data form.

```
313368 19931031 GEN MTR, FORD MTR
313368 19941031 FORD MTR, NEW VENT.., GKN AUTO.., GEN MTR

2134   19831031 GEN MTR, FORD MOTOR

2134   19841031 FORD MOTOR, GEN MTR

2134   19851031 FORD MOTOR

2134   19861031 GEN MTR, FORD MOTOR

...
...
...
61478  19801031 MCI COMM..., AM TEL &..., INTL BUS
```

Thanks for your help!

Hope you have a great day!

Comment: I think you need `df = df.groupby(['column A','column B'])['column D'].apply(list)` or `df = df.groupby(['column A','column B'])['column D'].apply(', '.join)`, it is dupe unfortunately

Comment: @jezrael Wow thank's a lot! It works well!

Comment: Oh, by the way, the results of that code seem not to have company number in every row, can you help me to fill them out?

Comment: Sure, add `.reset_index()` like `df = df.groupby(['column A','column B'])['column D'].apply(list).reset_index()`

Comment: Could you please transfer the comment which is the solution into answer, jezrael? Would best to keep track of the solution here. Thanks.